# Replaced SSD won't boot

Tags: hard-drive, high-sierra, startup, ssd

I have cloned the HDD from an old MBP (Early 2011) to a Kingston A400 SSD. When booting from USB it all works fine, however once installed internally when booting it shows a no entry sign  (I assume this is a kernel panic?).

I have also run `sudo trimforce enable` on the drive, but nothing changed. I have also tried SMC and NVRAM resets, to no avail.

Does anyone know how to make the drive work internally?

Comment: Press and hold the option key.  Can you find the bootable partition?

Comment: When connected by USB, for some reason it came up with two "Macintosh HD" partitions. When installed internally it does not show any and shows the  icon. Every now and then the apple icon flickers (as if its trying to boot) but returns to no entry.

Comment: That’s the prohibition sign meaning it that the boot partition is corrupt.  It’s a better bet if you write a clean version of macOS on your SSD rather than cloning from a HDD

Comment: I am currently trying a fresh install through recovery mode, however last time I tried that it got to the end of the process and says "cannot open file".